# Order Matrix visual with blanks to base

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this table in a Power BI file:

```
ImaginaryData = 
DATATABLE (
    "Fruit", STRING,
    "Colour", STRING, 
    "Rnk", INTEGER, 
    "Rnk2", INTEGER, 
    { 
        { "Apple", "R", 1, 2 }, 
        { "Apple", "G", 2, 3 },
        { "Apple", "B", 3, 1 },
        { "Apple", "Y", 4, blank()},
        { "Apple", "S", 5, blank()},
        { "Apple", "T", 6, blank()}
    } )
```

From it I have this matrix:

[image]

Because Rnk2 has some blanks in it if I try to order the table by the column Rnk2 I can have one of the following states:

[image]

[image]

What I want is for one of the above states to be the following:

[image]

How do I do this? Is there a way to force it to treat blanks differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had in the past a similar problem to solve. Maybe not the best solution but I resolved in the following way.

Add a calculated column to reorder the zeros to below:
[image]

And you can also removed the added column to see only your values:

[image]

Hope this can help you!